# Xcode 6.1 Attribute Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

After upgrading to Xcode 6.1 Beta 2 from Xcode 6 Beta 7, the following no longer works:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)
let colour = UIColor.redColor()
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour]
```

I have tried specifically declaring the dictionary as

```
let attributes: [NSString : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour]
```

but I am receiving the error "Cannot convert ... 'Dictionary' to 'NSString!'". Declaring the key as `NSString!` rather than `NSString` complains that `NSString!` is not hashable. Any clues?

Comment: for Xcode6.01 copied to playground - it works

Comment: Can confirm the code failed in XCode 6.1 Beta 2.

Comment: +1 The compiler errors surrounding this were extremely confusing. None of them even hinted that one of the items being added was an optional.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorted. As usual, the actual error is a red herring. `UIFont(name: , size:)` now has an `init?` initialiser, and so is optional. Correct usage is now :

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)! // Unwrapped
let colour = UIColor.redColor()
let attributes: [NSString : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour]
```

or, more correctly:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16) {
    let colour = UIColor.redColor()
    let attributes: [NSString : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour]
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just had this exact problem. I tried a few different modifications on my own (specifying dictionary type parameters, using `NSDictionary` instead), and all the compiler errors threw me in the completely wrong direction. Thanks!